# why ax is calculated in for loop when ax is independent of iterations while plotting subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I think the below given two snippets should result in same behavior because we are not using 'i' value to compute fig and ax, but I got two different plots for the codes below.

For the first code I got subplots in 7*2 grid and for the second one I got 1*2 grid with overlapping figures.

```
for i in range(n_rows):
    fg,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=n_cols,figsize=(12, 8))
    for j in range(n_cols):
        sns.violinplot(y=cols[i*n_cols+j], data=dataset, ax=ax[j])
```

or

```
fg,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=n_cols,figsize=(12, 8))
for i in range(n_rows):
    for j in range(n_cols):
        sns.violinplot(y=cols[i*n_cols+j], data=dataset, ax=ax[j])
```

Answer (score 2):

When you put `fg,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=n_cols,figsize=(12, 8))` inside the loop, it will be executed in every single iteration, resulting in those 7 different subplots.

With your logic, the following program would only print "Hello world!" once (since the value of `i` is not used in the print-statement), when in reality it prints 10 times.

```
for i in range(10):
    print("Hello world!")
```

Comment: I am iterating on n_rows but the value of n_rows is not used in finding fig,ax

Comment: I think you misunderstand how loops work. I added a small example to maybe clarify.